# Is it possible to "combine" two registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I'm a student, and this year - first year - we have to learn some programing languages. One of them is Assembly x86.

I would like to know if I can "combine" two register, and "use them as one".
I need to store a 64 bits key to decipher a text but the professor wants us to use mostly registers for our work.

The key will 'move', the least significient bit will be use to decipher one letter from the text, and one bit (result of some logical operation with bits in the key) will be add at the 'end' of the key.

Sorry for asking a silly question, and for my english.

Comment: Lookup the `shld` instruction. You can also use multiple registers as one using the carry flag. For example, to add two register pairs, use `add` for the low half and `adc` for the high halves.

Answer (score 0):

Not typical for processors to have this, but x86 does have this feature, al, ah, ax, eax, rax are "combined" as you call it.  You can access portions of the register.

With most/any useful instruction sets you can mask and shift and access portions of a register...

Answer (score 0):

In assembly, you don't really "combine" registers; they're independent storage, like unrelated independent variables in higher-level languages.  There are a few instructions that can use certain registers together, but for the most part, they're used independently.

What that means is that you don't "combine" the registers; you simply use the registers together.  So if you need to copy 64 bits, and you only have 32-bit registers, you just copy both pieces at the same time:

```
; Copy both halves of the key, the low part into eax, the high part into edx.
mov eax, [src]
mov edx, [src+4]

; Copy both halves out to memory somewhere.
mov [dest], eax
mov [dest+4], edx
```

If you need to shift the "bigger" value, you shift both registers at the same time.  There are two ways to do this:  You can either cleverly use shift and rotate instructions, or you can use the "combined" special `shld` and `shrd` instructions.

Let's look at how you'd shift a 64-bit combined key by one bit position, doing it the old-fashioned way:

```
shl eax, 1    ; Shift eax up one bit, putting its top bit into the carry flag.
rcl edx, 1    ; Rotate edx up by one bit, bringing in the carry flag at the bottom.

shr edx, 1    ; Shift edx down by one bit, putting its bottom bit into the carry flag.
rcr eax, 1    ; Rotate eax down by one bit, bringing in the carry flag at the top.
```

Now let's look at how you'd do it with the "newer" `shrd` or `shld` instruction:

```
shrd edx, eax, 1   ; Consider edx+eax together as a single register, and shift right by one bit.

shld edx, eax, 1   ; Consider edx+eax together as a single register, and shift left by one bit.
```

The `shrd` and `shld` instructions are written in the order of "high register" then "low register".

Note that while there's no such thing as a 128-bit equivalent of `shrd` and `shld`, the multi-instruction form can work for as many bits as you need.  For example, if edx+ecx+ebx+eax form a single "big" register, you could shift them up and down one bit at a time like this:

```
; Move everything up by one bit.
shl eax, 1
rcl ebx, 1
rcl ecx, 1
rcl edx, 1

; Move everything down by one bit.
shr edx, 1
rcr ecx, 1
rcr ebx, 1
rcr eax, 1
```

There are more efficient ways to shift even larger constructs by even larger sizes, but this is simple to understand, and it works.